# Deserialize object into assembly that is now signed and versioned

Tags: .net, serialization, strongname

I used to serialize a treeview with the BinaryFormatter (c#). The Assembly that did just that and which contains the all the serializable classes has now a strong name and is signed and also got a new version number (however, implementation didn't change).

When I try to deserialize the byte[] array, the line

```
(TreeViewData)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
```

produces an ArgumentNullException. (Parametername: type)

I thought the versionnumber is the problem, so I implemented an own Binder. I overwrote the BindToType method and made sure that the version is corrected and the correct type is returned.

However, at the very moment, the program leaves the BindToType method, I still get the exception mentioned above.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 12):

You can use a `SerializationBinder` to solve this:

```
private class WeakToStrongNameUpgradeBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        try 
        {
            //Get the name of the assembly, ignoring versions and public keys.
            string shortAssemblyName = assemblyName.Split(',')[0];
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(shortAssemblyName);
            var type = assembly.GetType(typeName);
            return type;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //Revert to default binding behaviour.
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
formatter.Binder = new WeakToStrongNameUpgradeBinder();
```

Voila, your old serialized objects can be deserialized with this formatter. If the type have also changed you can use a `SerializationSurrogate` to deserialize the old types into your new types.

As others have mentioned, doing your own serialization rather than relying on `IFormatter` is a good idea as you have much more control over versioning and serialized size.

Answer (score 3):

You could *try* using a serialization surrogate, but without something we can reproduce it will be hard to give a decent answer.

The fundamental problem, however, is that BinaryFormatter is simply very, very brittle when it comes to things like assemblies. Heck, it is brittle enough even [within an assembly](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/obfuscation-serialization-and.html).

It sounds like `TreeViewData` is tree based, so I wonder whether xml would have been a better (i.e. more version tolerant) option. If efficiency is a concern, there are custom binary formats (like [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)) that offer high performance, version tolerant, portable binary serialization. If your data is already serialized... I wonder if it might be time to change track? Try using the old assembly to deserialize the data, and switch to a more robust serialization strategy.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to never use the builtin serializes for your persistent storage. Always code your own if for no other reason someday in the future you will need to read and write your file formats from another language.