# Deserialize Object using Newer Version of Strong-Named Assembly

Tags: c#

I have a class in a strong-named assembly, and this class is serialized using NetDataContractSerializer.

When I rebuild the assembly deserialization fails because the strong name has changed.

(I have noticed that in the XML output of the serializer I can just delete the version information of the assembly and this makes it work as desired).

What is a good approach to solve this problem?  I much prefer to use the built-in .net classes rather than third-party or roll my own.

Using .Net 4.6

Comment: Even if you solve your problem, you will face similar serialization problems. .Net built-in serialization mechanisms (XML or Binary) have constraints that diferent versioned serialized entities will not be able to deserialized in the future. Unless requirement forces, I strongly recommend Json serialization which will provide you great flexibility.

Comment: I resolved this using matt howells answer here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780739/deserialize-object-into-assembly-that-is-now-signed-and-versioned